# Connecting an iPhone 4s with an iPad3 using Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can anyone point me to an example of connecting an iPhone 4S to an iPad 3 using BLE?

I have written a sample App and when I use CBCentralManager like this:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];
```

To scan for devices the iPhone and iPad do not seem to see each other.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should emphasize that you are using bluetooth low energy (4.0) and not regular bluetooth 2

Answer (score 2):

The iPad is not a Bluetooth Low Energy device. A BLE device is typically a wristwatch, heart-rate monitor etc.

This is why you can't see the iPad using CoreBluetooth.

Consider using GameKit for iPhone-iPad bluetooth communication?

Comment: A BLE device can be anything, but most used in sports gear because of its low power consumption.

Comment: iPad-3 & iPhone-4S both are BLE compatible. List of iOS devices that are BLE compatible are iPhone 4s or later,
iPad (3rd generation) or later,
iPad mini or later,
iPod touch (5th generation) or later.

Answer (score 0):

The new iPad (3rd Gen) does have Bluetooth 4.0, but you cannot use BT4.0 to communicate between two iOS devices.

You can only communicate with external sensors.

Comment: Not quite. GameKit allows you to communicate between iOS devices. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Yes, but not with bluetooth 4.0 (which it seems he is using from his code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers,  the bluetooth specification states that dual mode blend devices will use the classic bt radio and not the ble radio. You can only use the ble radio with single mode ble devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between two iDevices with bluetooth low energy you have to wait for iOS 6, which will support server functionality on BLE.